# how to get data from CSV file to form on NumericUpdown controls in C#

Tags: c#

I want to get CSV file values in my C# form controls.(TextBox, NumericUpDown,ListBox)
I have one list say Names and one button Load
When i click load button values in CSV like Name,Age,RollNo.
should be added in List Box with Name field and on click of Name from ListBox
Values for Name,Age,Roll No should be shown in TextBox and NumericUpdown.
Plz help i am new to C#......

Answer (score 0):

As you're new to C# (and by the way you phrased your question, new to programming in general) I think writing a CSV parser by yourself might be asking too much - fortunately there are libraries to do this for you. Just read through this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader which contains a link to the code you can download and include in your project.

`NumericUpDown` isn't a "data" control - it just lets the user select a single value from a range of numbers. I can't see how you could use that control in the context of data from a CSV file (unless the control is to edit a single field value in a single row of a CSV file, of course).

Everything else you've described sounds like simple event-based programming. Just wire-up a handler for the `ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event and populate your form from there.